# Eclipse Workspace - Project is missing required libraries

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I was using this Workspace (Workspace A) for my team's main web application. I was using it last week & everything was fine, logged back into this Workspace to work on something & suddenly this error pops up. I didn't update the project (externally via file explorer, command line, etc.) or even internally via Eclipse...

Any idea why this error happened? And any tips/action items on preventing such errors from happening again in the future?

[image]

I've noticed this is a recurring issue with Eclipse, where errors will just appear overnight in a workspace, even when I had seemingly not made any changes to the workspace/project's configuration

Appreciate any insight into the matter, cheers!

Comment: Any changes to `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: @PM77-1 hey there, can you clarify? i didn't make any changes to the CLASSPATH, actually i didn't make any changes to this project's configuration for that matter

Comment: oh did you mean to say there could be changes to `CLASSPATH` & that's what caused this issue? i don't think there were any changes, but just so i can check on my end, how do i check if there are any changes, is there some way i can check/verify this?

Comment: Did you perhaps remove your gradle cached files? Is that your home directory it's complaining about? If so, are those files actually present?

Comment: @nitind hi thanks for responding, no i don't usually touch the cached files' location via file explorer or anything... i don't meddle with these files & configuration stuff in general unless i run into errors like this... & yeah to mention again what i said, i didn't touch anything or make changes to anything related to the workspace, came back & it's like this

Comment: Please show the `.classpath` files of both projects, _CoreConfigAPI_ and _CoreConfigServiceTier_. Did you run Gradle outside of Eclipse for those projects?

Comment: @howlger  hey i did run gradle outside of the project, is that what caused the issue? pardon the beginner-esque questions i'm going to ask as i've no prior experience with build tools -- how does Eclipse behave with regards to building projects? I noticed that when i want to run the application, it builds the project, is there a configuration Eclipse is using to build the project? because in my team's documentation, we have a specific gradle command to run `gradle clean build eclipse [other gradle program arguments]`

Comment: also, whenever i change certain values in the `.properties` files & a `.sqlmap-config.xml` file, the changes don't get reflected in the project because it is still pointing to the older values -- what i did to fix it was to remove the project from Eclipse, deleting the `build`, `.classpath`, `.project` files, rebuilding via the command line & then adding back the project to Eclipse. Does setting up a `Gradle Task` Run Configuration in Eclipse with the gradle program arguments we use help to fix this?

Comment: Do not use the `eclipse` argument when running Gradle. Import the project without `.classpath`, `.project` files and `.settings` folder, so Eclipse will create those files.

Comment: but if i don't include the `eclipse` argument, i won't be able to import the project into Eclipse -- Eclipse can't detect the project. How i import a project is "Import" -> "General" -> "Existing Projects into Workspace", should i use "Import" -> "General" -> "File System"?

Answer (score 0):

no idea what exactly caused the issue, but i reset up my workspace again (created a new workspace called `"Workspace A - 2"`) & got everything back up & running again.

Comment: Please show the `.classpath` files of both project from the old workspace to find out what actually went wrong so that it can be avoided in the future instead of using this workaround.